# Override port number specified in VM args for OSGi

Tags: eclipse, osgi

I am trying to run some OSGi bundles specific a specific port number via VM arguments in the run configuration.  But it seems like it is ignoring the VM args and using port 80 instead.

Here are my VM arguments:
-Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -Dorg.osgi.service.port=10080 -Ddsconfig.dir=C:/temp/wlm -DwlmDebugPrint=true

The program arguments are just the vanilla ones:
-os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -nl ${target.nl} -console

Ideas for what to check are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:  It should be

-Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -Dorg.osgi.service.**http**.port=10080 -Ddsconfig.dir=C:/temp/wlm -DwlmDebugPrint=true